# Adding participants in a group chat

Tags: meteor, sweetalert

I am trying to add participants in a group chat but I am not getting any error but nothing is happening here is my code:

```
Meteor.methods({
    addMember: function(groupId,email){
       Groups.update({_id:groupId},
       {$addToSet: {participants:{"emails":email}}}
     );
   }
});
```

My event:

```
  Template.editGroup.events({
  'click .add': function() {
    var id = this._id;
      swal({
              title: "An input!",
              text: "Add an email address:",
              type: "input",
              showCancelButton: true,
              closeOnConfirm: false,
              animation: "slide-from-top",
              inputPlaceholder: "Add email address"
          },
          function(email) {
              if (email === false) return false;
              if (email === "") {
               swal.showInputError("You need to add email  address!");
                  return false
              }
              Meteor.call("addMember",id,email)

          })
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you update with your Groups database schema please

Answer (score 0):

The id is the first parameter of a meteor collection update.

See in: https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-update

try it

```
Meteor.methods({
    addMember: function(groupId,email){
       Groups.update(groupId,
       {$addToSet: {participants:{"emails":email}}}
     );
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using dot notation to update the `emails` field inside `participants`.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/document/#document-dot-notation

Just replace `{$addToSet: {participants:{"emails":email}}}` with

`{$addToSet: {"participants.emails":email}}`